# PC(s) wont post - Memory Error

Tags: xeon

I am in the final stages of building two PCs, but upon testing, neither pass POST.

When turned on, fans spin and lights flash but there's no BIOS screen and motherboard error related to memory.

PC 1 - Gives error 53
PC 2 - Gives error 19

What we have tried so far:

1. Removing all components except MOBO, CPU and PSU
2. Inserting one RAM stick, tried each slot
3. Clearing CMOS (Button press and Jumper)
4. Updated BIOS (PC1)

Any Ideas?

See build below:

#### PC 1

MOBO - Asus X99M WS
CPU - Xeon E5-2697 V4
RAM - Kingston 64GB PC4-2133 CL15 288-Pin RDIMM Kit (4x16GB)
GPU - Quadro M4000
SSD - Samsung 850 Pro
PSU - EVGA Supernova 650W Gold
Case - Silverstone TJ08-E

#### PC 2

Mobo - Asrock Fatality X99M Killer
CPU - Xeon E5-2697 V4
RAM - Kingston 64GB PC4-2133 CL15 288-Pin RDIMM Kit (4x16GB)  KVR21R15D4K4/64
GPU - Quadro M4000
SSD - Samsung 850 Pro
PSU - EVGA Supernova 650W Gold
Case - Silverstone TJ08-E

Answer (score 1):

Both these motherboards appear to only support Xeon V3 processors.  The LGA2011-V3 socket will fit an LGA2011-V4 processor but a bios update is required for compatibility and if it's unavailable it will not work.

If you're positive you're running a BIOS version capable of supporting V4 you may want to purchase a single stick of DDR4 from a local store to check that your RAM is good given that it's all from the same vendor/manufacture.